# ERROR java.lang.Class when running on travis-ci, absent when run locally

Tags: java, grails, travis-ci

While running integration tests of my Grails 3 app on travis-ci I encounter

```
ERROR java.lang.Class - Failed to call close before the object was scheduled to
be garbage collected
```

This error does not happen when running tests locally. I could not find any documentation or related SO questions even mentioning this error
Is this error related to insufficient resources? Is there any documentation that could help me debug it?

EDIT1: Documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html describes this as "a rather serious situation caused by abnormal circumstances", this does not really help to debug this issue however